# Ideas on hump in basement floor?

Tags: concrete, basement

Our basement flooded recently and we are in the process of redoing it. The slab floor has always had this hump in it, figured it just settled.

But I pulled off a piece of the hump and there is gravel below it and beneath the gravel you can see the original floor. You can see an outline where the cement was built up here.

Any ideas why this hump was built up like this? Planning on breaking it out so we can level and put new flooring down but concerned why anyone would do this.

[image]
[image]

[hump in basement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfoUZ.jpg)

[close up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZc9k.jpg)

Comment: Your pictures aren't very clear but I think I see what you're calling a hump, it's a rectangular raised platform.  That might be to create a level surface for storing something, or for a furnace, and to protect it from minor flooding.

Comment: How old is the house?  Your walls show moisture issues, did you already address those on the exterior?  I'd bet that was a pad for a boiler/furnace and there was possibly an original low grade floor that was lower than the pad and someone then wanted to finish it cheaply with out chipping out the appliance pad and just concreted over it to make it look like the rest of the floor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. Yes definitely a rectangle pad that's been leveled out with the rest of the floor so an old appliance makes sense.

Comment: House was built in 1955. Has had a lot of moisture issues over the years. Looks like the basement has a flooded a few times before. But the outside has been graded properly and french drain plus second sump pit added.

Answer (score 1):

The concrete could have been made out of using dirty sand, also, it could be the result of inadequate mixing, especially with the small capacity mixer, or too much mixing water that tends to wash out the cement and form honeycombs (loose aggregates with a little or no cement bond).

I suspect your floor has many such defects. You may try to detect the defective spots by knocking the slab with a metal rod. The quality hardened concrete will respond with a crispy banging sound, while the problematic location will respond with a muffled sound.

Depends on the quantity of the problemed concrete, you can fix a small number of bad spots by digging up the defective concrete and enlarging the hole by chipping until reaching the sound concrete, then refill clean gravel to level with the original bottom of the slab, give it a slight tamping, then place well-mixed concrete. However, for more than just a few bad spots, hiring a reputable contractor may be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So this is the only raised spot on the floor. Also, you can see a flat floor surface right beneath the gravel in the second picture. So this hump was definitely added after the original floor was put down. Just no idea why. Maybe to raise some old appliance? But that seems very unlikely.

Comment: The current floor could be an addition to the damaged old floor. The crumbling concrete seems odd though.